# Matlab code to translate xml file into a struct and then this struct should be converted into an excel file of a specific format

Tags: excel, matlab, struct

I am currently developing MATLAB code that takes an XML file, converts it into a struct by using `xml2struct` (which I have already done) and then the main objective is to convert this struct array into an Excel sheet of a specified format.(format mentioned below)

For example, if a particular XML is:

```
 <RoadXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.4.0" versionRevision="2.4.0-$Revision: 23033 $-$Date: 2011-05-02 11:01:27 +0200 (lun., 02 mai 2011) $">
  <Network name="" traffic="right-hand">
     <Geolocalisation Azimuth="0" EPSG="3857" WKT="PROJCS
        <Translation x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
     </Geolocalisation>
```

Then the excel file should be:

```
RoadXML.Network.name = ""
RoadXML.Network.traffic = right hand
```

The values should be on the 2nd column in the excel sheet

I am new to MATLAB coding

https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28518-xml2struct

Comment: So what have you done so far ?

Comment: So far i have translated the xml file into a struct by using 'xml2struct' and accessed all the elements in it.by using 'getfield' command.Now the work is to arrange the tags and values according to the format i specified

Comment: xml2struct is not a standart MATLAB procedure, it would be usefull to provide it in your question

Comment: thank you .added in the question

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Add a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then enhance your question. There is not enough information to help you.

Comment: You state that the main point of your question is to write to Excel. However, you entire question is actually about creating the struct... which is it? It also looks like you're missing a bunch of `>` from your XML. Please give us a small example of your actual XML, at least a link to the [`xml2struct`](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28518-xml2struct) function you're using, the code you've used to create the struct, and your desired Excel output. This way we can recreate your issue, and suggest how to create the desired output.

Comment: I have edited the question.I have added the right xml code also and how i want it to be shown on the excel sheet..Hope it is clear now

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a copy of Matlab but i would suggest to use [struct2cell](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html?s_tid=doc_ta) then [xlswrite](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html?searchHighlight=xlswrite&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) with something like this :

```
xlswrite('out.xls',sruct2cell(datastruct));
```

where datastruct is given by your `xml2struct` function.

Comment: No it does not work.It show this error :Warning: ActiveX - invalid argument type or value 
> In xlswrite>ExecuteWrite at 267
  In xlswrite at 214